# ArcGIS Network Analyst not recognizing One-way Restrictions?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, network-analyst, route

I have created a network and have been attributing my various routes in a domain with a one-way field. At current all values are From-To (FT) in the one-way field. However the network does not honor the one-way restrictions.

I figure its within the VB script but I cannot work it out.

For example the road below has a One-Way set for FT  but is not honored nor does the network recognize it if using Network Identify Tool.

[image: Road Oneway Attributes]

Network identify tool showing transferable in both directions

[image]

I am also using the default values Arc provides upon recognizing a field, as seen below:

From-To

[image]

To-From

[image]

Both source data and network edges are running in the correct direction (shown by arrow at end symbology). Oneway attribute is set to FT, but the network still shows its completely traversable.

[image: Directionality]

Answer (score 1):

You may not have Evaluators set for your FT and TF fields in Network Analysis:

[image]

Source:
https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000008060

> FT or F indicates a one-way street permitting travel only in the
>   digitized direction of the edge. TF or T indicates a one-way street
>   permitting travel only against the digitized direction of the edge. N
>   indicates a street that does not permit travel in either direction.
>   Any other value indicates a street that permits travel in either
>   direction.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/creating-a-network-dataset.htm

Comment: I believe so yea, thought I was on the right track with this here. Both From-To and To-From are Type: Field and Value: Expression with the exact expression that you have posted, with the FT/TF changed obviously.  Edit: Also the default values are set to 'Use Restriction'

Comment: Check your digitised direction of your network - see updated edit above

Comment: I have double and triple checked the direction of both the source data and the network edges and they are running in the correct direction. See latest edit. Still completely stumped, it's probably something simple, or its arc being arc....... thanks for your help so far though.